# Read array of strings from XML file

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have following class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Resource
{
[XmlAttribute("name")]
public string m_Name { get; set; }

public string[] ItemDrop;

}
```

And this XML file:

```
<ResourceData>
<Resources>
    <Resource name="Iron Ore">
        <ItemDrop type="array">
            <value>Iron Piece</value>
        </ItemDrop>
    </Resource>
    <Resource name="Tree">
        <ItemDrop type="array">
            <value>Log</value>
            <value>Leaves</value>
            <value>Apple</value>
        </ItemDrop>
    </Resource>
</Resources>
</ResourceData>
```

I'm trying to deserialize file and place those two Resource objects in array.

It properly reads m_Name but there is nothing in ItemDrop array.

This is how i load data:

```
public static ResourceContainer Load(string path)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ResourceContainer));
    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize(stream) as ResourceContainer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mark it with XmlArray and XmlArrayItem to specify the inner structure.

Comment: Works fine, thank you sir! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You surely need `XmlArrayItem` attribute:

```
public class Resource
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string m_Name { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem("value")]
    public string[] ItemDrop;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try xml Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Resource resourse = new Resource();
            resourse.ReadXML(FILENAME);
        }
    }

    public class Resource
    {
        public static List<Resource> resources { get; set; }
        public string m_Name { get; set; }
        public string[] ItemDrop;

        public void ReadXML(string filename)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
            resources = doc.Descendants("Resource").Select(x => new Resource() {
                m_Name = (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                ItemDrop = x.Element("ItemDrop").Elements("value").Select(y => (string)y).ToArray()
            }).ToList();
        }

    }
}
```